# Retrieve entity related with itself from DataBase with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, graph

I have an entity in my Java code like this

```
public class Point{

   private Float Lat;

   private Float Long;

   List<Point> neighbors;

};
```

So I want to persist this information in a Data Base. My idea was to use Hibernate and forgget about to create the tables and the relationships. Obviously the List<> neighbors needs to create a new table for the relation.

This information, it's need to be retrieve by a Web Service in orden to find the shortest path between two points, as a graph.

So I don't know how it works this internally. If I retrieve a Point X from the DataBase, Hibernate will have the reference of X and will retrieve the Points of the list neighbors in case to be needed.
But, of this points in the List, I need the points which are in those List, and so on...

As

```
Y = X.neighbours.elementAt[i].
Y.neighbours.elementAt[j].doSomeStuff...
```

In orden to cover all the graph to find the shortest path.

Is this posible this with the framework?

And, how can I load the database with a sql script.

As

```
INSERT INTO POINT VALUES....

INSERT INTO NEIGHBOURS VALUES...
```

Which will be the syntaxis like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to change your List for a Set and map it:

```
<set name="neighbors" table="point_table" cascade="all" fetch="join" lazy="false">
    <key>
        <column name="id"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="package.Point"/>
</set>
```

Doing this, when you take a Point from db, it will have its related points

Comment: Thx! That was just what I need! And this is done for all points? I mean, I take a point, so I retrieve the Set<> for that point, which have more points so also retrieve the set of those points?

Comment: Yep, every point comes with their related points so you have to be careful with cyclic references

Comment: So this trigger my second question. Imagine a graph with 500 points (to say a number, could be 1million). This means that I will have all those points in memory in my Web Service. Is this advisable? Or the lazy property make that Hibernate retrieve the points only in the moment I need? This trigger other question, is advisible to have many interactions with the DB to look for each point?

Comment: I am not an expert at this point but taking 1 million points at a time is surely not a good idea because it would take a long time so I would choose to make more (but shorter) interactions with DB. If you set lazy="true", set will be loaded on demand and not eagerly so this might be the best choice in this case. (PS: if this mapping worked for you, please select it as accepted answer so future users know it worked plz)